# Как можно добавить Имя автора поста в таблицу Django?

Tags: python, django

Я разрабатываю сайт на Django где есть возможность выкладывать посты.
Как я могу внести в БД автора поста?

```py
'''views.py'''
def create_post(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('crypto')
        else:
            error = 'Invalid Form!!!'

    form = PostForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error,
    }
    return render(request, 'crypto/create-post.html', context)

#models.py
class Post(models.Model, ):
    author = models.TextField()
    title = models.CharField('Название поста', max_length=125)
    text = models.TextField('Описание')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: Автор должен как-то быть связан с учётными записями на сайте? Сейчас сделано текстом, а вообще обычно используют ForeignKey на модель User.

Comment: Вместо `author = models.TextField()` лучше использовать `author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts", on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что посты выкладывают авторизованные пользователи.
Поэтому текущего пользователя можно найти в `request.user`, и при создании поста сохранить в `Post`:

```py
if form.is_valid():
   new_post = form.save(commit=False)
   new_post.author = request.user.username
   new_post.save()
```

---

PS - но обычно вместо текстового поля для автора, создают `ForeignKey` с моделью `User`.